# time command don't let me use -f with bash functions

Tags: bash, time

I'd like to use time command in a bash script to calculate the elapsed time of some function, but time command gives me error messages when I try to call it to measure one of the script's functions using any of its options, like '--format', which I want to make use of.

The same thing happens if I use 'time [...]' from terminal, with any command. However, using it from terminal, it works when I enter '/usr/bin/time [...]' instead of just 'time [...]', but when I call '/usr/bin/time ANY_FUNCTION_INSIDE_ANY_SCRIPT [arguments]' in a script, it complains about the called function being not a valid command.

test.sh code:

```
#!/bin/bash

testime ()
{
    printf "test message is \"$1\" \n"
    printf "just testing...\n"
    sleep 5
    read -p "enter something: " buffer
    echo $buffer
}

time -f "testime() finished after %E" testime "damn!"
printf "Bye bye!\n\n"
exit
```

Output:

```
$ ./test.sh
./test.sh: line 12: -f: command not found

real    0m0.001s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.001s
Bye bye!
```

BUT... If i use time without options, like "-f ...", as here:

```
[...]

time testime "damn!"
printf "Bye bye!\n\n"
exit
```

...the script works correctly, as you can see:

```
$ ./test.sh
test message is "damn!" 
just testing...
enter something: SOMETHING_I_HAVE_ENTERED
SOMETHING_I_HAVE_ENTERED

real    0m24.050s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.001s
Bye bye!
```

AND when I call '/usr/bin/time -f [...]', as it would work when I'm doing stuff from terminal, using '-f [...]' or not, it gives me some output like this:

```
$ ./test.sh
/usr/bin/time: cannot run testime: No such file or directory
Command exited with non-zero status 127
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed ?%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 340maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+72minor)pagefaults 0swaps
Bye bye!
```

Does someone know why it happens?

Answer (score 0):

Mention the command and -f option at the end.

```
Shell> time testime 'damn!' -f 'testime() finished after %E'
test message is "damn!"
just testing...
enter something: abc
abc

real    0m7.513s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.003s
```

The usage of the test command clearly mentioned that you need to give command before to options.

```
NAME
       time - time a simple command or give resource usage

SYNOPSIS
       time [options] command [arguments...]
```

In `[options]` only `-P` is given and remaining are arguments.